# C# WHy does Array.IndexOf return -1

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, types

I have started trying to learn c#.

I don't understand why my use of `Array.IndexOf();` returns -1.
I want it to return the index numbers in the `alphabet` based on the letters in a `player_name` that you get from user input. I am trying to loop through the characters of the
`player_name` and capture the index number of that character in the alphabet.

Take a look:

```
using System;

namespace FantasyGame
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string player_name = null;

            string[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "æ", "ø", "å", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "æ", "ø", "å" };

            Console.Write("\nEnter your name: ");
            player_name = Console.ReadLine();


            string[] password = { };
            foreach (char c in player_name)
            {
                int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c);
                Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c));
                Console.WriteLine(c);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace the `c` variable with a specific string value such as `"k"` it returns the correct index number. Why? The ´´´c´´´ has a string value, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The `c` has a string value, right?

No, it has a `char` value. You can see that where you've declared the variable:

```cs
foreach (char c in player_name)
```

There are numerous fixes for this. I'd suggest the simplest is to just make `alphabet` a string and use `string.IndexOf`. Alternatively, to keep your code as similar as possible, make `alphabet` a `char[]`, e.g. by using `String.ToCharArray`:

```cs
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøåabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå".ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c);
```

with

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c.ToString());
```

see [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0),

`alphabet` is an array of string, so we should pass a string to the second parameter of `Array.IndexOf`

Answer (score 2):

Your **c** is not a `string` value, is a `char`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are comparing "c" which is of type `Char` with an alphabet letter which is of type `String`. What you can do is just change the type of the array you are using to `Char[]` like this.

```
char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
                    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                    'æ', 'ø', 'å', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
                    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                    'x', 'y', 'z', 'æ', 'ø', 'å' };
```

Also pay attention to the quotes in which char types use **single quotes** ' ' but string types use **double quotes** " " .

Answer (score 2):

MSDN Documentation of `Array.IndexOf()` says

> Searches for the **specified object** and returns the index of its first
> occurrence in a one-dimensional array or in a range of elements in the
> array.

---

Now in your code,

- If you look at closely, your `alphabet` array is an array of `string`
- your code `int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c)` is trying to find unicode char value in alphabet string and that is why you are getting -1 as a result.
- To make it work, type of `alphabet` and type of `c` needs to be same. Same in the sense, if alphabet is a `char[]` then `c` **should** be char.
- You can achieve it in two ways,

  1. Converting `alphabet` as an array of `char`
  2. Converting `c` to string.

---

First Approach,

```
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøåabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå".ToCharArray();
int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c);  //here alphabet is a type of char array
```

Second Approach,

```
string[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "æ", "ø", "å", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "æ", "ø", "å" };

int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c.ToString());
```